# change tab at specific time of the day

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide();//Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show();//Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });
});
```

i have am using "#tab1" and "#tab2" for the div id

i am not able to figure out how to use the specific url to change the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's this.  Replace the default action with the relevant code below (keeping the click event). You'll also need to name each of the "li" items that make up the actual tabs, so that you can determine which one will be selected to be displayed at the right time of day. Then, you'll check which one you want to be shown, and show it accordingly.

```
if (timeOfday == NightTime) {
   $(".tab_content").hide();//Hide all content
    $("#liForTab1").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $("#tab1").show();//Show first tab content

} else { 
   $(".tab_content").hide();//Hide all content
    $("#liForTab2").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $("#tab2").show();//Show first tab content

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be a double equal sign?  `if ( x == y )`

Comment: Thank you so much but the content of the tab is showing but the tab is not selected.

Comment: @sparky672 - yes  it should.Srry.  @amanda --  You need to add the 'active' class to the LIST ITEM, not the tab. I modified the answer to fix that issue.